# When building React Native for iOS or Android using Visual Studio App Center, how do you use the Build Number as part of the App Version number?

Tags: react-native, visual-studio-app-center

When building React Native for iOS or Android using Visual Studio App Center, how do you use the Build Number as part of the App Version number? For example: Major.Minor.Build where Major and Minor are configured by the dev team, but Build is provided by App Center.

Comment: New approach here... In the iOS Build there is `CFBundleShortVersionString` (ex: 1.2.10) and a `CFBundeVersion` (ex: 13) and Android Build there is a `versionName` (ex: 1.2.10) and a `versionCode` (ex: 13). The `CFBundleVersion` and the `versionCode` are what AppCenter increments when doing a build.

I am going to use `CFBundleShortVersionString` and `versionName` as Release Family (ex: #.#) managed in code and let AppCenter manage the `CFBundleVersion` and `versionCode` as a proper build number. This will allow the release  to stay the same across stores but for the builds to be different..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

New approach here... In the iOS Build there is `CFBundleShortVersionString` (ex: 1.2.10) and a `CFBundeVersion` (ex: 13) and Android Build there is a `versionName` (ex: 1.2.10) and a `versionCode` (ex: 13).

The `CFBundleVersion` and the `versionCode` are what AppCenter increments when doing a build. I am going to use `CFBundleShortVersionString` and `versionName` as Release Family (ex: #.#) managed in code and let AppCenter manage the `CFBundleVersion` and `versionCode` as a proper build number.

This will allow the release to stay the same across stores but for the builds to be different